# Switching camera between objects retrieved from array

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’m working on a three.js project in which I’m adding many mesh objects to the scene through an array. Each individual object in the array has a specific name property, and I’m working out how to add the camera perspective to the individual object by that name, so you can switch views upon user input.

The fiddle below demonstrates the core of my project. It’s 50 added meshes divided into 10 scenes. The first dropdown is to let you switch scenes, the second is meant to be a “zoom in” device so you can look at each object pretty close. Upon user input, it already displays the name of the object you’ve selected like so:

```
var data = [{
    "Host name": "Object1"
}];
//One example of an object inside the array

var objectname = data[objectNumber - 1]["Host name"];
document.getElementById("hostname").innerHTML = objectname; //outputs name
objectname.add(camera);
```

You can see I’m halfway there. But how do I zoom in on the selected object as well? I thought a simple `objectname.add(camera)` would do it but it’s not. I could be going about it the wrong way.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqx60dtz/) with the code.

Comment: I've changed your code a bit. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/w14by2fg/) But from my point of view, it's not a good idea to have a common list of objects for all scenes, it's better to have a list of objects for each scene.

Comment: Is there another way to go about it without using `getObjectByName`? Your fiddle works fine, it's just the way I want it, but for some reason I can't implement that line of code into my project. It keeps saying obj = undefined and I really couldn't tell/show you where it differs from the basic set up in the fiddle

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. I just copied the whole fiddle into my work and applied the necessary changes, but I couldn't say what made it say it's undefined. Anyway, thank you!